# PTV VISSIM COM with Python Script

Tags: python

I am using the following script to get All the Vehicles objects from link 1 and link 3 at an intersection in PTV Vissim.

```
def main():
TimeDiff = 1
DistLimit=200.00
SpeedLimit=47.00
DesiredSpeed=50


#Get All the vehicle objects on link 1 and 3.
Vehicles1=  Vissim.Net.Links.ItemByKey(1).Vehs.GetAll()
Vehicles3=  Vissim.Net.Links.ItemByKey(3).Vehs.GetAll()

#Iterate through every vehicle in link 1.
for Vehicles1 in Vehicles1:

    #Get attribute vehicle. (Atime1 = Arrival Time of Vehicle at Intersection)
    ArrTime=Vehicles1.AttValue("ATime1")
    DesSpeed = Vehicles1.AttValue("DesSpeed")
    Current_Speed1=Vehicles1.AttValue("Speed")


#Check if there any Vehicles on link 3.
if len(Vehicles3)>0:
#Iterate through every vehicle in link 3.
 for Vehicles3 in Vehicles2:
    #Get attribute of vehicles on link 3. (Atime3 = Arrival Time of Vehicle at Intersection
       ArrTime3=Vehicles3.AttValue("ATime3")
       DesSpeed = Vehicles3.AttValue("DesSpeed")
       DistSigHead2=Vehicles3.AttValue("DistanceToSigHead")
       OrgDesSpeed = Vehicles3.AttValue("OrgDesSpeed")

       if (ArrTime2-ArrTime)<TimeDiff:
        Current_Speed1=Vehicles3.AttValue("Speed")
        newDesSpeed=Current_Speed1-2
        Vehicles3.SetAttValue("DesSpeed", newDesSpeed)
        if DistSigHead2 ==0:
            Vehicles3.SetAttValue("DesSpeed", DesiredSpeed)
```

The script is able to get all the vehicle objects and perform given conditions. But the for loop just checks vehicle one time when it enters in link 1 or 3 and compares its attributes with the vehicle on the other link. I want to check every vehicle in each time step in link 1 and 3 and compare there arrival times. I think I am not applying the for loop correctly. Anyone, please suggest me something in this regard.

Your help and guidance in this regard will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks logically wrong, although it won't generate an error:

for Vehicles1 in Vehicles1:

Now, re-write the script as shown below:

OLD SCRIPT:

## Iterate through every vehicle in link 1.

````
#OLD SCRIPT
for Vehicles1 in Vehicles1:
    #Get attribute vehicle. (Atime1 = Arrival Time of Vehicle at Intersection)
    ArrTime=Vehicles1.AttValue("ATime1")
    DesSpeed = Vehicles1.AttValue("DesSpeed")
    Current_Speed1=Vehicles1.AttValue("Speed")

#NEW SCRIPT:
for Vehicles1b in Vehicles1:
    #Get attribute vehicle. (Atime1 = Arrival Time of Vehicle at Intersection)
    ArrTime=Vehicles1b.AttValue("ATime1")
    DesSpeed = Vehicles1b.AttValue("DesSpeed")
    Current_Speed1=Vehicles1b.AttValue("Speed")```
````